# How do I open another window in macOS in Swift with Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode8

I am working on a macOS app that presents a list of customer master records in a table view. Double-clicking a row in the table view should open a new window where the user can view and edit the customer information.

This is an Xcode 8.3.3 project using a storyboard and Swift.
It is not a document or core data app.

I have the main window working up to the point where the table view is displaying the records correctly and the associated view controller is receiving the double-click events and logging them to the console.

I have created an additional window controller and view for the edit window and verified its basic functionality by temporarily marking it as the initial controller.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to display a new instance of that window when the user double-clicks a row.

Thanks to @Joshua Nozzi I'm closer. Here is the code at this point.

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "xyzzy") as? NSWindowController
{
  windowController.showWindow(self)
}
```

It's generating a

> (Storyboard: 0x620000000680) doesn't contain a controller with
>   identifier 'xyzzy'

error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Introduction.html) is a great place to understand how windows are managed in general.

Specifically (assuming you know how to present a window controller scene in storyboards), you need somewhere to store references to the new window controllers so they’re not immediately deallocated (and disappear) when presented.

In your case, you may want to keep an array of your open detail windows in the master window controller, so that if the master goes away, the details do as well. When a detail window is open (a controller instance is created and its window shown), you’ll store its controller in the array; when closed, you remove its controller from the array so it’s deallocated.

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on how much control you want, how you want child window ownership to work, etc., but this basic pattern is usually sufficient.

To instantiate a new window controller scene from a storyboard:

```
var myWindowController = NSStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardFileName", bundle: nil)?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MyWindowControllerIdentifier") as MyWindowControllerClass
myWindowController?.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: I haven't read the Window Programming guide cover-to-cover, but I did spend about an hour in it earlier this morning and did not find an example of how to actually instantiate the new controller and display the window and view. The current window is being automatically displayed by whatever Xcode created when I created my project. Also, I'm new to Swift & Cocoa, but am a very experienced developer in general.

Comment: Ah. In that case, see the addition to my answer. :-)

Comment: Cool. I was on the right track hours ago. Question now is where does the window controller identifier come from?

Comment: You set it in Interface Builder. Select the controller and set its identifier in I think the second tab of the inspector. (Not in front of me right now :-)).

Comment: Okay. Did that. Getting no controller error. Please see the addition to my original post for the code at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you set the storyboard identifier for the *window controller* and not the *window*? It's actually the third tab and when the controller is selected, it's under Identity, called "Storyboard ID". It's case-sensitive, of course.

Comment: That was it. Turns out clicking the window controller window in the storyboard selects the window inside the controller. You have to click the window controller "title bar" (where the controller and first responder icons live), instead. Thanks very much for the assist.

Comment: Yep. I had a feeling. :-D Glad I could help.

Comment: The tool bar is not working

Comment: I suggest posting a new question about your toolbar problem with _a lot more_ detail.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, to open new window, this code can help you

> windowController.contentViewController = tabViewController

The full code is like that i used it in my project:

```
@objc func openApplicationView(_ sender: Any?) {
    let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "tabView") as? TabViewController
    let windowController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "secondWindow") as! TabViewWindowController
    windowController.showWindow(self)
    windowController.contentViewController = tabViewController
}
```

It can helpful if you've closed the **mainWindow**. So you need to add one **windowController** and **tabViewController**(you can use normal view controller) in your own underlying storyboard.

In my side the tabViewController has been extended by **NSTabViewController** and tab view component has been bound with this class.

Note: I've also added the windowController in my **Main.storyboard** as a component and identified to use then on coding side.