# Display window from the menu bar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I was wondering if there was a way in Xcode to, instead of displaying the normal menu items or popovers, display a normal window coming from the menu bar, similar to how third party apps like [CleanMyMac](https://cdn2.macpaw.com/images/content/Real-TIme%20Protection%20Monitor_1570631314.png) do it.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: A menulet is a full fledged `NSApplication`. You can attach XIBs and storyboards

Comment: @vadian Yes, but I've never encountered any that go beyond just a simple drop-down list of items.

Comment: Is "from the menu bar" from a menu or from a status item?

Comment: Does CleanMyMac display a window or a view in a menu item?

Comment: @Willeke It's from a status item. I'm not sure exactly what type of thing it displays, the attached photo drops directly down from the status item.

Comment: See [How do I open another window in macOS in Swift with Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119813/how-do-i-open-another-window-in-macos-in-swift-with-cocoa)

Comment: If you click outside of it does it disappear like a popover? Or stay open like a window?

Comment: @Loengard It disappears

Comment: So it's probably just a popover without the arrow triangle.